# Spring-Data Couchbase - How to set TTL to document?

Tags: java, spring-data, couchbase, nosql

I am using Spring-Data Couchbase project (1.1.1.RELEASE) over a Couchbase Cluster in version 2.2.

I need to set up some Time To Live properties on my documents.

I know how to do it with CouchbaseClient object but I don't know how to do it using Spring-Data Couchbase abstraction.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean 'Time to **Live**' instead of 'Time to Leave'?

Comment: Yes I do mean Time To Live, sorry, it's a misspell :)

Answer (score 1):

To set a TTL you set the expiry value on the document:

```
@Document(expiry = 10)
```

This will set the TTL to 10 seconds. The Spring-Data Couchbase [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/couchbase.entity.html) covers this in more details.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. I have read the documentation but I should have missed this line.

Comment: I want to do same thing in code , is there any other way to do it via code.